# Subpage with custom post types inside another cpt

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following doubt. Currently I can create subpage fakes in wordpress. Creating for example: single-video.php, single-review.php. Using ACF and then rewriting with a rewrite rule and creating the post appears on every page the way I want it. cpt / post-name / video or / review and so on. However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom post as follows. CPT / post-name / cpt / post-name. It would bind the cpt with another cpt. Is it possible to make this association? Or does someone point the way to it?...

Comment: Yes, you could create one CPT with a rewrite rule to set it to `/cpt-1-post-name/` and a second CPT with a rewrite rule to set it to `/cpt-1-post-name/cpt-2-post-name/`, though depending on your needs it might make more sense to just make one CPT which is hierarchical and includes the "parent" post name followed by "child" post name.

Comment: I created the custom page for videos, another for reviews, another for news and another for images. However, I think of putting trailer 01 and trailer 02. But that has, url / cpt / post-name / video01, and the second video has cpt / post-name / video02. But without me having to create a new page called single-video02.php. What I want to do is publish videos or images. That the url understands that it is a continuation or something bound that post, continuing the url of the same post. It is in this part that I am facing difficulties in elaborating.